# well-posedness of a mathematical model

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

what is the meaning of Well-posedness of a mathematical model of a physical phenomena for example stokes equation in fluid dynamics ?

what is the necessity to prove that a model is well-posed?

how we can prove that a mathematical model is well-posed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about mathematical physics but here is what we mean by saying a problem is well-posed.

A well-posed problem satisfies 3 conditions:

$(1)$: the solution exists

$(2)$: The solution is unique

$(3)$: The solution continuous depends on data

For prove, it is really depends on the problem you are studying... I don't know there is a general way of it...